# Robot on a grid. Find if it can reach a certain position.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have a robot that can move :
(+2, - 1) (-2,  +1) (+1, +3) (-1, - 3) .  I have to show whether it will reach a certain position (x,  y) 
I've done that on a computer,  recursively,  but  I can't  find  a recurrence formula.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you written the set of positions that it can reach (starting presumably at the origin?) as an explicit description?  The recurrence formula would simply be: set $S$ contains the starting position, and also contains $(x,y)+(a,b)$ for any $(x,y) \in S$ and any $(a,b)$ in your list of moves.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $(-2,1) = -(2,-1)$ and $(-1,-3) = -(1,3)$, so if we define the vectors $\vec u = (2,-1)$ and $\vec v = (1,3)$, the set of the robot's admissible positions consists of all linear combinations $$k\vec u + m \vec v,$$ for integers $k, m$.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see how that will help me. Does the pair (x, y)  have to form a vector  equal to k(2, - 1) or k(1,3) ?

Comment: Already figured it out  thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Following heropup's solution, you can reach points that can be written in the form $k(2,-1)+m(1,3)$ where $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

This means you can reach points of the form $(2k+m,-k+3m)$.  If we call such a point $(a,b)$, we note that $3a-b=3(2k+m)-(-k+3m)=7k$.  So every reachable point $(a,b)$ satisfies the condition that $7$ divides $3a-b$.

Conversely, if $(a,b)$ is any point satisfying the divisibility condition, $7\mid 3a-b$, then we can write $(a,b)=(a,3a+7t)$ for some integer $t$.  And $(a,3a+7t)=-t(2,-1)+(a+2t)(1,3)$.
So any such point is reachable.

Summarizing $(a,b)$ is reachable if and only if $7$ divides $3a-b$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an illustration of heropup's answer for a robot starting at the origin. The black dots are the landing points of the robot.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did the same simulation on  computer